# Visual Studio Code Intellisense code completion for constructor function methods

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, autosuggest, javascript-intellisense

I need a very simple feature in VS code but I cannot find it. I have searched a lot about it and some articles shows to add jsconfig.json file to the root directory. I have added it but it did not solve my problem.
Here is a simple example to explain what I expect:

I have a js file called "Adder.js" with the following code:

```js
AdderClass = function(){
    this.add = function(x, y){
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Also, I have a CalculatorClass with the following code:

```js
Calculator = function(){
    var adder = new AdderClass();
    this.Calculate = function(x, y){
        return adder.add(x, y);
    }
}
```

When I am typing "return adder." I expect VS Code shows me the add function, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

use this extension it is vry helpfull and it will show all methods in javascript

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode

Comment: Hi Nadim,
I have this extension, but it did not help to solve the above problem. Have you ever tried what I explained as an example?

Comment: So, what's wrong with my configuration? Can you guide me?
Do you have any jsconfig.json? If yes may I see its content?